# How to run Behat on docker from within PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm, behat

I have a php application running on docker. I installed Behat and successfully run the tests from the CLI using this command: `docker run -v $(pwd)/app/:/app/:rw gmail-priority-inbox vendor/bin/behat`.

Now I'm trying to run Behat from within PhpStorm, mainly to be able to debug using Xdebug.

When I try to run it, PhpStorm tells me it can't find Behat executable:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: When you tried it, the docker container was running? If yes stop the container then try again to detect your Behat service. (PhpStorm starts the Docker container automatically)

Comment: Please check if the same works in terminal if you're not using `$(pwd)`

Comment: @adampweb I tried stopping the docker container and re-run from phpStorm but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Dmitrii I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. If I run `docker run -v $(pwd)/app/:/app/:rw gmail-priority-inbox vendor/bin/behat` from the terminal it works. The problem is I need to debug to figure out why a scenario is not working

Comment: Ok so I got a little bit of progress. I got the error to disappear by changing my project settings "PHP/Test Frameworks". I added a new entry to map Behat to my docker. The behat version is detected ok but when I try to run it I get "Can not find behat autoloader file by directory: '/app/vendor/bin'". What I find strange is this at the beginning: "[docker://gmail-priority-inbox:latest/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php" since I changed the path mapping to match my environment